# query to find latest row of data in a table

Tags: mysql

i am a clomplete noob to mysql.
have this assignment question using select in a query to find the latest entry in a table.
The table has the following Columns:EMPID, NAME, POSITION, SALARY, DEPTCODE, BOSSID

PRIMARY KEY is EMPID, but EMPID not autoincremented.

EMPID is entered as EMPID1000, or EMPID5000

the numbers are not sequential

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is

```
select * from your_table 
order by substring_index(EMPID,'EMPID',-1) asc ;
```

Here is an example

```
mysql> create table test (empid varchar(100),name varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> insert into test values 
('EMPID1000','A'),
('EMPID1001','B'),
('EMPID5000','C'),
('EMPID4000','D'),
('EMPID2000','E'),
('EMPID3000','F');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test order 
by substring_index(empid,'EMPID',-1) asc ;
+-----------+------+
| empid     | name |
+-----------+------+
| EMPID1000 | A    |
| EMPID1001 | B    |
| EMPID2000 | E    |
| EMPID3000 | F    |
| EMPID4000 | D    |
| EMPID5000 | C    |
+-----------+------+
```

So you can use `desc` with limit 1 to get the last latest one

```
mysql> select * from test 
order by substring_index(empid,'EMPID',-1) desc limit 1 ;
+-----------+------+
| empid     | name |
+-----------+------+
| EMPID5000 | C    |
+-----------+------+
```